# Density of android phones

Tags: android

I am confused about the density of the Android phones. I want to know the screen resolution of high density, medium density, and low density Android phones.

I also want to know the density of HTC Google nexus and Droid.  Can any one help me with this?

Answer (score 3):

To add to Andrei's answer.

To help out with your burden you could always use: http://members.ping.de/~sven/dpi.html to calculate the dpi.

And [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Android_devices) lists a lot of different devices so it's only for you to go through them and calculate. Of course if it's not stated somewhere else like sven's calculator. 
But first read through http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

You should read http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

It will answer to many your questions.

Google Nexus One and Motorola Droid have hdpi (in practice, all phones, not tablets, with 480x800 and higher resolutions, have hdpi, 320x480 phones - mdpi)